Apache2 web page not loading from outside network/internet
I am struggling with an Apache2 web server and cannot load the page from outside the local network.
The server is running on a PC in local network, connected to the router with internet access, with port forwarding.
From the local network I can load the web page on any device, but it will give a timeout from outside local network.
The TCP 80 & 433 ports are open, nmap finds them open, if I disable the rule to allow the ports through the firewall (managed by firewalld), the loading of the page will also fail locally. But, if I check the ports with an online tool, they are reported as closed - this I don't understand.
The DNS addresses are ok, I can telnet and ping the domain. Telnet also connects on port 80, but I don't know how to test further with telnet.
The port forwarding works, as requests from internet reach the apache server, I can see this in the apache logs (I replaced names for domain and server with "my_domain" and "servername"):
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815041 2024] [core:trace5] [pid 1679] protocol.c(713): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Request received from client: GET / HTTP/1.1
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815530 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(435): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Headers received from client:
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815612 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Host: "my_domain".eu
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815682 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815749 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815815 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815879 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.815941 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   DNT: 1
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816004 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Connection: keep-alive
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816066 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_request.c(438): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816275 2024] [apparmor:trace1] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(116): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Dumping uri info scheme='(null)' host='(null)' path='/' query='(null)' fragment='(null)'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816430 2024] [apparmor:trace1] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(148): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] aa_enter_hat (:no path:) n:0x0 p:0x0 main:0x0
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816696 2024] [apparmor:trace1] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(168): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Dumping scfg info: scfg='0x7f18799a9e60' scfg->hat_name='(null)'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816769 2024] [apparmor:debug] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] [scfg] adding server_name '"servername"."my_domain".eu' to aa_change_hat vector
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816834 2024] [apparmor:debug] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(187): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] [vhost+uri] adding vhost+uri '"servername"."my_domain".eu-/' to aa_change_hat vector
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816897 2024] [apparmor:debug] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(192): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] [uri] adding uri '/' to aa_change_hat vector
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.816957 2024] [apparmor:debug] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(196): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] [default] adding 'DEFAULT_URI' to aa_change_hat vector
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.817429 2024] [apparmor:trace1] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(212): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] AA checks: aa_getcon result is 'apache2//null-"servername"."my_domain".eu', mode 'complain'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.817522 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1679] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.817596 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1679] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.817661 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 1679] request.c(360): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818115 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(168): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type 'text/html' ...
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818198 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... did not match 'application/xml'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818261 2024] [filter:trace2] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(185): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' did not match
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818325 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(168): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type 'text/html' ...
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818386 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... did not match 'application/wasm'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818446 2024] [filter:trace2] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(185): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' did not match
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818509 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(168): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type 'text/html' ...
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818570 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... did not match 'application/rss+xml'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818630 2024] [filter:trace2] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(185): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' did not match
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818691 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(168): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type 'text/html' ...
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818751 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... did not match 'application/x-javascript'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818810 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... did not match 'application/javascript'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818870 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(180): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... did not match 'application/ecmascript'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818928 2024] [filter:trace2] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(185): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' did not match
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.818988 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(168): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type 'text/html' ...
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.819048 2024] [filter:trace4] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(174): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] ... matched 'text/html'
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.819180 2024] [filter:trace2] [pid 1679] mod_filter.c(185): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' matched
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.819277 2024] [deflate:trace1] [pid 1679] mod_deflate.c(773): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] token: 'gzip' - q: ''
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822117 2024] [deflate:debug] [pid 1679] mod_deflate.c(909): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 10701 to 3023 : URL /index.html
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822298 2024] [http:trace3] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(1141): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] Response sent with status 200, headers:
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822374 2024] [http:trace5] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(1150): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2024 13:13:52 GMT
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822437 2024] [http:trace5] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(1153): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Server: Apache/2.4.59 (Debian)
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822516 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Nov 2023 20:38:02 GMT
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822610 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   ETag: \\"29cd-60a4aff03779a-gzip\\"
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822682 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Accept-Ranges: bytes
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822745 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Vary: Accept-Encoding
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822809 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Content-Encoding: gzip
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822872 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Content-Length: 3041
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822935 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.822997 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Connection: Keep-Alive
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.823059 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 1679] http_filters.c(971): [client 5.14.141.46:37810]   Content-Type: text/html
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.823554 2024] [core:trace6] [pid 1679] core_filters.c(828): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] writev_nonblocking: 3380/3380
[Fri Apr 26 16:13:52.823797 2024] [apparmor:trace1] [pid 1679] mod_apparmor.c(247): [client 5.14.141.46:37810] exiting change_hat: dir hat (null) dir path :no path:
root@"servername":/etc/firewalld/zones# 


The tcpdump shows messages in both directions, also on client side, but no data comming in:
****@Asus-A55V:~$ sudo tcpdump -i any -v port 80
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
16:13:52.792156 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43323, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    Asus-A55V.37794 > "my_IP".http: Flags [S], cksum 0xd2ac (correct), seq 752409867, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1530110980 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:52.792186 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6058, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [S], cksum 0x46ea (correct), seq 2080905614, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1530110980 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:52.829283 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    "my_IP".http > Asus-A55V.37810: Flags [S.], cksum 0x0850 (correct), seq 1378020679, ack 2080905615, win 65160, options [mss 1370,sackOK,TS val 2616942565 ecr 1530110980,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:52.829326 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6059, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [.], cksum 0x3330 (correct), ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530111017 ecr 2616942565], length 0
16:13:52.829343 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 58, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    "my_IP".http > Asus-A55V.37794: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7495 (correct), seq 2392051795, ack 752409868, win 65160, options [mss 1370,sackOK,TS val 2616942565 ecr 1530110980,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:52.829351 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43324, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.37794 > "my_IP".http: Flags [.], cksum 0x9f75 (correct), ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530111017 ecr 2616942565], length 0
16:13:52.829471 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6060, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xdb88 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530111017 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:13:53.108031 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6061, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xda71 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530111296 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:13:53.396027 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6062, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd951 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530111584 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:13:53.940020 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6063, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd731 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530112128 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:13:53.972017 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40589, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59452 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x7886 (correct), ack 649900761, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520610469 ecr 3687389861], length 0
16:13:53.972046 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38214, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59446 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0xfba7 (correct), ack 2634497546, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520610469 ecr 3352852067], length 0
16:13:53.997856 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 3382, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59452: Flags [.], cksum 0xa057 (correct), ack 1, win 273, options [nop,nop,TS val 3687399939 ecr 2520590425], length 0
16:13:54.001306 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 38936, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59446: Flags [.], cksum 0x23ce (correct), ack 1, win 265, options [nop,nop,TS val 3352862163 ecr 2520590330], length 0
16:13:54.996031 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6064, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xd311 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530113184 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:13:57.300027 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6065, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xca11 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530115488 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:13:57.829924 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43325, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.37794 > "my_IP".http: Flags [F.], cksum 0x8bec (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530116017 ecr 2616942565], length 0
16:13:57.858525 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 58, id 51666, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    "my_IP".http > Asus-A55V.37794: Flags [F.], cksum 0x783e (correct), seq 1, ack 2, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2616947594 ecr 1530116017], length 0
16:13:57.858562 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43326, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.37794 > "my_IP".http: Flags [.], cksum 0x7829 (correct), ack 2, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530116046 ecr 2616947594], length 0
16:14:01.652063 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb911 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530119840 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:14:04.212074 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40590, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59452 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x2928 (correct), ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520620709 ecr 3687399939], length 0
16:14:04.212104 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38215, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59446 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0xac37 (correct), ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520620709 ecr 3352862163], length 0
16:14:04.265791 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 3383, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59452: Flags [.], cksum 0x783d (correct), ack 1, win 273, options [nop,nop,TS val 3687410205 ecr 2520590425], length 0
16:14:04.265820 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 38937, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59446: Flags [.], cksum 0xfbb4 (correct), ack 1, win 265, options [nop,nop,TS val 3352872428 ecr 2520590330], length 0
16:14:10.100041 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6067, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 426)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9811 (correct), seq 1:375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530128288 ecr 2616942565], length 374: HTTP, length: 374
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: "my_domain".eu
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    
16:14:14.452013 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40591, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59452 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0xd90d (correct), ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520630949 ecr 3687410205], length 0
16:14:14.452038 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38216, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59446 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x5c1e (correct), ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520630949 ecr 3352872428], length 0
16:14:14.484967 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 3384, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59452: Flags [.], cksum 0x5053 (correct), ack 1, win 273, options [nop,nop,TS val 3687420423 ecr 2520590425], length 0
16:14:14.492746 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 38938, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59446: Flags [.], cksum 0xd3c3 (correct), ack 1, win 265, options [nop,nop,TS val 3352882653 ecr 2520590330], length 0
16:14:21.412875 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 6068, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.37810 > "my_IP".http: Flags [F.], cksum 0xc211 (correct), seq 375, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1530139600 ecr 2616942565], length 0
16:14:21.523701 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38217, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59446 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [F.], cksum 0x188c (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520638020 ecr 3352882653], length 0
16:14:21.523720 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40592, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59452 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [F.], cksum 0x9582 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520638020 ecr 3687420423], length 0
16:14:21.552538 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 38939, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59446: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfde3 (correct), seq 1, ack 2, win 265, options [nop,nop,TS val 3352889712 ecr 2520638020], length 0
16:14:21.552558 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38218, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59446 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0xfcda (correct), ack 2, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520638049 ecr 3352889712], length 0
16:14:21.555632 enx021860676100 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 59, id 3385, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http > Asus-A55V.59452: Flags [F.], cksum 0x7aca (correct), seq 1, ack 2, win 273, options [nop,nop,TS val 3687427490 ecr 2520638020], length 0
16:14:21.555641 enx021860676100 Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40593, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    Asus-A55V.59452 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x79c6 (correct), ack 2, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2520638052 ecr 3687427490], length 0
^C
36 packets captured
36 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel


Tried also with ufw, disabling apparmor (not really working as kernel module).
As a summary (with my understanding):

apache2 - ok (loading from local network)
ports open and forwarded -ok (telnet, tcpdump and apache log)
DNS - ok
I think the answer from apache can only be filtered out by the firewall...
So, if anyone can help, I would apreciate it!

